# Can CNTK run on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: cntk

I'm new to Microsoft CNTK. I did some research and I couldn't find any projects regarding running CNTK locally on a raspberry pi. I can't attempt it yet since my raspberry pi is still traveling overseas. My question is, can you run Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit on a raspberry pi ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to run evaluation/inference on raspberry pi 3, but not training itself, right? We have a prototype running CNTK Evaluation on ARMv8 architecture, e.g. Ubuntu on PINE64 or Debian on Qualcomm 410C dragonboard, but we have not tested on raspberry pi 3 though.